# Using Celery to send email in Flask Admin

Tags: python, celery

I have been developing a Flask Admin app which also had an API. Part of the app included a function that sent an email when called. I was advised I should use celery to send the email.

I followed the advice on https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask

I added the following code:

config.py:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://redis:6379/0"
```

**init**.py

```
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
```

Previously the code was:

```
@app.route('/api/postupdate', methods=['POST'])
@auth_token_required
def post_update():
    if not request.json[0]:
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Request not in JSON'}), 400)

    updates = []
    for entry in request.json:
        updates.append({'trackingnumber':entry['trackingnumber'], 'date': datetime.strptime(entry['date'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), \
                'status':entry['status'], 'location':entry['location']})
    send_email(updates)
    return make_response(jsonify({'success': 'Update added'}), 200)
```

I changed the line from `send_email(updates)` to `send_email. delay(updates)`

I then added `@celery.task` on top of `def send_email()`

However, now, the emails are never sent. I am not even sure where to beginning trying to troubleshoot. No errors are thrown and the program continues as if it was successful.

Everything is in separate docker containers. Here is my docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - PG_PASSWORD=postgres
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    links:
      - dev:uwsgi
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./x/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  redis:
    image: redis
    ports:
        - "6379:6379"
  dev:
    build: ./x/
    volumes:
      - ./x/app:/code/app
    expose:
      - "3031"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - redis
  scraper:
     build: ./Scraper/
     volumes:
      - ./Scraper/scraper.py:/code/scraper.py
      - ./Scraper/x.py:/code/x.py
     depends_on:
      - db
      - dev
```

After advice received I have made the following amendments:

Added the following to docker-compose.yaml file as a new service

```
celery:
    build: ./Worker/
    links:
      - redis
    volumes:
       - ./x/app:/code/app
```

run.sh:

```
celery worker -A app.celery
```

The new dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ENV TERM xterm

 RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y python3-pip python3.5-dev      build-essential libpq-dev nano

ADD ./requirements /code/requirements
ADD run.sh /code/run.sh

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r /code/requirements/base.txt

WORKDIR /code
RUN chmod 777 run.sh
CMD  "./run.sh"
```

This now results in the celery service exiting immediately with the code 1.

Answer (score 0):

What your setup has done so far is to put your email tasks in a queue managed by redis, but you don't execute your tasks yet.

To execute yout tasks you need to run an additionally docker container where your run the celery worker process (to execute the tasks)!

In the blog 
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask 
some lines before **Conclusion** you find the following instruction to run the celery worker:

> On the second terminal run a Celery worker. This is done with the celery 
>   command, which is installed in your virtual environment. Since this is the 
>   process that will be sending out emails, the MAIL_USERNAME and MAIL_PASSWORD 
>   environment variables must be set to a valid Gmail account before starting 
>   the worker:
>
> ```
> $ export MAIL_USERNAME=
> $ export MAIL_PASSWORD=
> $ source venv/bin/activate
> (venv) $ celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info
> ```

Your new container has to be linked to the redis container and has to contain the same volume as your `dev` container.

Comment: Thank you for that. I am not sure how I missed it. I have amended the question to add the changes I have made to the program. This now results in the celery service exiting immediately with the code 0. I am getting a bit confused as to how the celery service should work. For it to send the email using boto.ses and ninja templates it must need access to the code but I don't know how it's meant to know where to look for it.

Comment: Can you post  `ls -r x/app`

Comment: Running that from within the dev container gets: `utilities.pyc  utilities.py  templates  models  email.pyc  email.py  config.py  api.pyc  api.py  __pycache__  __init__.pyc  __init__.py`

Comment: Your directory structure looks OK. I assume the `celery = Celery...` instruction is ins `__init__.py` so that the `run.sh` started in `/code` directory should find the `celery` object in the `app` module (hence `-A app.celery`). Check if you have this variable name correct. If it is Ok, then add the full traceback of the `celery worker` call to the OP.